# Blackberry - cannot find "Run on simulator" option on Eclipse on Mac OSX

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I followed the instructions titled ["Creating your first app"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/30946/Creating_your_first_app_1806946_11.jsp) to get my first app set up. However when I right click on the project and select Run As, I can't see an option for running on a simulator! What am I missing?

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: right click on project explorer -> run as -> Blackberry Simulator click on that.

Comment: @BBdev I cannot see the option for Blackberry Simulator in Run as. I have attached the screenshot in my question.

Comment: edit your question that you are doing it for Mac OSx

Comment: @BBdev done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackberry Offers Simulator for Windows platform alone. Not for linux or mac.
So you couldn't able to start simulator on MAC...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to Test your applications directly in the Device: BB Simulators for Smartphones only run in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I found you cannot run the simulator on Mac OSx!

Comment: you should tell this in the question that you are doing it on Mac OSx